# Related questions are going off the screen

Tags: bug, design, asking-questions, related-questions

Consider this image:

[image]

When you ask a question and put in all of the content(title, body, etc.), a whole bunch of Related Questions show up. If you scroll to the top(on a Mac, at least) and scroll further, the related questions will appear beyond the Stack Overflow bar.

Title of Q: Fatal error does not stop program execution, and debugger does not show up

Comment: Coulnd't repro that exact issue but I did have the "do you want to ask on meta?" box disappear partially behind the header and when scrolling down the related questions came on top of the footer.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe because my title generated a *lot* of questions. @ivarni

Comment: Could be. I just copypasted a random question from the frontpage. Either way there is definetely some issues with that thing.

Comment: I would suggest that you give us the actual title so that we can test this ourselves? If you posted the question to SO anyway, then the title must be one of the questions under your account. So no point in obscuring it.

Comment: I have not posted the question yet, but here is the title anyway: "Fatal error does not stop program execution, and debugger does not show up"

Comment: How do you get related question in that yellow box? Depending on what I focus (title input, body text area, tag input), I get different instructions in the yellow box, but never related questions.

Comment: Should be posted as an answer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness perhaps.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. What browser?

Comment: Chrome, try the title of my question... @Shog9

Comment: [chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TKg9.png), [firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzWoJ.png)